# demultiplexing UDP/RTP multi program transport streams

Tags: audio, video, streaming, directshow

I'm dealing with UDP/RTP multi program transport streams with Directshow.
I wish to decode in a single graph the audio channels brought by different programs.
How can I configure the Demultiplexer in order to achieve this?

Using GraphEdit, the basic graph composed by:

Network receiver ---> MS Demultiplexer ---> PSI parser

allows me to see the program list and audio/video channels associated to each program.
If I select program, audio and video PIDs in PSI parser properties, the contents are rendered.
Now, how can I render multiple channels from different programs at the same time, in the same graph?

I tried:

1) via PSI parser properties dialog. The 1st configured is OK, but as I configure the 2nd audio/video/program, the old content rendering is replaced by the new configuration. Building a graph via API with this approach brings the same result: only the 1st configuration works. If I add other pins, I can render contents only if the configuration is the same as the 1st pin. If the audio/video PID belongs to a different program, it is not rendered.

2) cascading two (or more) Demuxes, configuring the 1st to forward packets belonging to the specific program and the 2nd to extract audio and video from the stream received. For this configuration, output pin media type = "transport stream", mapped to "Transport packet (complete)"; the PID is the program PID identified by PSI parser.
Result: the graph runs, but I got a black window and no audio.

Can you help, please?

Comment: I think you manually have to configure the demux filter. (without using the psi parser).

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a tee filter after the demux and then adding multiple parsers to the output pins from the tee? I think that might work.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it now is I use ffmpeg and generate multiple outputs. Then use separate FFmpeg instances to encode those streams separately. The only possible issue is that I use Linux and this may not be ideal for other operating systems.

Here is the master FFmpeg command:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "udp://@server_ip:8080?overrun_nonfatal=1&reuse=1" \
-map 0:p:1 -copyinkf -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts "udp://server_ip:8001" \
-map 0:p:2 -copyinkf -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts "udp://server_ip:8002" \
...
-map 0:p:10 -copyinkf -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts "udp://server_ip:8010"
```

Then you can have single FFmpeg instances running something like this:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "udp://@server_ip:8001" -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -f mpegts rtmp://other_server:port
```

Hope this helps put someone in the right direction. I wish it were this simply explained when I needed help.